# Spring cloud stream kafka timeout when getting topic information

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have a kafka server in house which we've been using with spring boot applications without an issue. I'm now trying to implement a simple solution for spring cloud stream and I'm getting a timeout when it tries to list topics. It definitely connects to the kafka server OK, it's only when getting topic information that it fails. This is a really simple implementation just to test.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-binder'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: doLightMeasured;onLightMeasured
    stream:
      bindings:
        doLightMeasured-out-0:
          destination: light_measured
        onLightMeasured-in-0:
          destination: light_measured
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: 10.72.88.234:30092

logging:
  level:
    root: debug
    org:
      springframework: debug
```

AsyncApiTestApplication.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AsyncApiTestApplication
{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncApiTestApplication.class);

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(AsyncApiTestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Supplier<LightMeasured> doLightMeasured()
    {
        return () -> {
            // Add business logic here.
            return new LightMeasured();
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<LightMeasured> onLightMeasured()
    {
        return data -> {
            // Add business logic here.
            logger.info(data.toString());
        };
    }

}
```

and the logs show the following:

```
2023-09-15T18:15:08.166+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating connection to node 10.1.2.3:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address /10.1.2.3
2023-09-15T18:15:08.168+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Queueing Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1694794568167, tries=0, nextAllowedTryMs=0) with a timeout 30000 ms from now.
2023-09-15T18:15:08.196+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2023-09-15T18:15:08.740+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
2023-09-15T18:15:08.741+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
2023-09-15T18:15:08.804+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=0, headerVersion=2) and timeout 3600000 to node -1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.4.1')
2023-09-15T18:15:08.876+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Received API_VERSIONS response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=0, headerVersion=2): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=13), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=4, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=5, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=6, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=7, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=56, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=65, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=66, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=67, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=0, finalizedFeatures=[], zkMigrationReady=false)
2023-09-15T18:15:09.012+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 has finalized features epoch: 0, finalized features: [], supported features: [], API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 13 [usable: 13], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Metadata(3): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], StopReplica(5): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], AlterPartition(56): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], UpdateFeatures(57): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], Envelope(58): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): 0 [usable: 0], ListTransactions(66): 0 [usable: 0], AllocateProducerIds(67): 0 [usable: 0]).
2023-09-15T18:15:09.013+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending MetadataRequestData(topics=[], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to 10.1.2.3:9092 (id: -1 rack: null). correlationId=1, timeoutMs=29146
2023-09-15T18:15:09.015+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2) and timeout 29146 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
2023-09-15T18:15:09.020+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=0, host='10.1.2.3', port=9092, rack=null), MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=2, host='10.1.2.5', port=9094, rack=null), MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=1, host='10.1.2.4', port=9093, rack=null)], clusterId='Jq68U7chSbqx0lNgUK-Xiw', controllerId=1, topics=[], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
2023-09-15T18:15:09.024+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Updating cluster metadata to Cluster(id = Jq68U7chSbqx0lNgUK-Xiw, nodes = [10.1.2.5:9094 (id: 2 rack: null), 10.1.2.3:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), 10.1.2.4:9093 (id: 1 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = 10.1.2.4:9093 (id: 1 rack: null))
2023-09-15T18:15:09.025+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Resolved host 10.1.2.4 as 10.1.2.4
2023-09-15T18:15:09.025+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating connection to node 10.1.2.4:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) using address /10.1.2.4
2023-09-15T18:15:09.029+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node 1
2023-09-15T18:15:09.029+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Completed connection to node 1. Fetching API versions.
2023-09-15T18:15:09.029+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node 1.
2023-09-15T18:15:09.029+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2) and timeout 3600000 to node 1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.4.1')
2023-09-15T18:15:09.037+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Received API_VERSIONS response from node 1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=13), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=4, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=5, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=6, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=7, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=56, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=65, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=66, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=67, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=0, finalizedFeatures=[], zkMigrationReady=false)
2023-09-15T18:15:09.038+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 has finalized features epoch: 0, finalized features: [], supported features: [], API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 13 [usable: 13], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Metadata(3): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], StopReplica(5): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], AlterPartition(56): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], UpdateFeatures(57): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], Envelope(58): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): 0 [usable: 0], ListTransactions(66): 0 [usable: 0], AllocateProducerIds(67): 0 [usable: 0]).
2023-09-15T18:15:09.039+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending MetadataRequestData(topics=null, allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to 10.1.2.4:9093 (id: 1 rack: null). correlationId=3, timeoutMs=29983
2023-09-15T18:15:09.039+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=3, headerVersion=2) and timeout 29983 to node 1: MetadataRequestData(topics=null, allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
2023-09-15T18:15:38.177+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating close operation.
2023-09-15T18:15:38.178+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Waiting for the I/O thread to exit. Hard shutdown in 31535999999 ms.
2023-09-15T18:15:38.179+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Hard shutdown in 31535999998 ms.
2023-09-15T18:16:08.177+02:00  INFO 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Disconnecting from node 1 due to request timeout.
2023-09-15T18:16:08.183+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight METADATA request with correlation id 3 due to node 1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 59130ms, elapsed time since send: 59130ms, request timeout: 29983ms): MetadataRequestData(topics=null, allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
2023-09-15T18:16:08.184+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Requesting metadata update.
2023-09-15T18:16:08.186+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1694794568167, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1694794568284) timed out at 1694794568184 after 1 attempt(s)

java.lang.Exception: DisconnectException: Cancelled listTopics request with correlation id 3 due to node 1 being disconnected
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$Call.handleTimeoutFailure(KafkaAdminClient.java:848) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$Call.fail(KafkaAdminClient.java:817) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.handleResponses(KafkaAdminClient.java:1262) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1421) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1344) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-09-15T18:16:08.202+02:00  INFO 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
2023-09-15T18:16:08.211+02:00  INFO 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
2023-09-15T18:16:08.211+02:00  INFO 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2023-09-15T18:16:08.211+02:00  INFO 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
2023-09-15T18:16:08.211+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Exiting AdminClientRunnable thread.
2023-09-15T18:16:08.212+02:00 DEBUG 13664 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Kafka admin client closed.
2023-09-15T18:16:08.213+02:00 ERROR 13664 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception encountered for light_measured
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:372) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:91) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:286) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:345) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:303) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:307) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:647) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.asyncapitest.AsyncApiTestApplication.main(AsyncApiTestApplication.java:19) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1960) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2095) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:408) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:382) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:359) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You have 3 brokers: 10.1.2.3:9092, 10.1.2.4:9093, 10.1.2.5:9094. Your app fails to connect to 10.1.2.4:9093 (after the initial connection to 10.1.2.3:9092). If you `$ telnet 10.1.2.4 9093` or `$ nc -vz 10.1.2.4 9093` from the machine starting Spring, does it timeout? (to check if the port is properly open)

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneD, worth a try, but I can telnet and nc without any issues.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the call to API_VERSIONS gets a response, but the listTopics always has timeout issues (even if it connects to the same kafka server). I've also tried downloading an example (https://github.com/ehsaniara/scs-kafka-intro) which generates exactly the same errors. I've listed the topics on the kafka servers and they definitely have not been created.

The interesting thing is that I can connect to the same kafka using a different spring boot without cloud stream. This is on the same developer workstation and it works without any problems.